# Converting an Unsigned Long to Binary in C

Tags: c, binary, long-integer

I am trying to convert an unsigned long to binary in C.

```
char* long_to_binary(unsigned long k)

{
        static char c[65];
        c[0] = '\0';

        unsigned long val;
        for (val = ULONG_MAX; val > 0; val >>= 1)
        {   
            strcat(c, ((k & val) == val) ? "1" : "0");
        }
        return c;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? It prints out the incorrect values. I tried printing out `val` and instead of printing the base2 values are off by one. So it prints like `3 7 15 ....` I tried initialising the value to ULONG_MAX+1 instead of ULONG_MAX but then it doesn't even enter the loop.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a binary digital computer all information is already strored in binary format. And using `strcat` to successively build a string is not really a good idea. How do you expect the string to look like after you appended another single character?

Comment: `ULONG_MAX` is the **maximum** value an `unsigned long` can hold. What do you think `ULONG_MAX + 1` does?? Use a debugger to step through your code. At least print the values in the loop. The reason it fails is pretty obvious.

Comment: Something is wrong. Show the test program, so we can run it as well.

Comment: `ULONG_MAX` will have all bits set to 1. Obviously using that as a mask is not what you want. It seems you want to init `val` to be a mask with the most significant bit set. Try `val = 1 << (sizeof(val) * 8 - 1);`

Comment: ULONG_MAX is 0xffff....ff, you need 0x8000...0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing `val` to have all bits set.  So when you apply the `&`, the result of the comparison will be false unless `k` has all bits set.

You only want one bit set in `val`, and you need to start with the highest bit.  So initialize it like this:

```
for (val = 1UL << (sizeof(unsigned long)*8-1); val > 0; val >>= 1) {
```

Then when you call it like this:

```
printf("binary=%s\n",long_to_binary(0x12345678));
```

You get this:

```
binary=0000000000000000000000000000000000010010001101000101011001111000
```

Comment: when you use a magic number, please at least document it. it took me 10 seconds to realize that by 8 mean you mean CHAR_BIT.